# How to implement useMemo hook to sort the table by name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use useMemo hook to sort the table by name without updating users state directly so component doesn't have to re-render. I'm having trouble implementing useMemo correctly as when I click on name header, sortByName() gets called then I get 'invalid hook error'. Ideally, I want to implement sort by ascending or descending, but before that I would like to get this work first. What am I doing wrong here?
https://codesandbox.io/s/clement-awad-intermediate-react-interview-practice-jmeh4?file=/src/App.js:0-1882

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20

export default function App() {
  let [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const flattenObj = (obj) => {
    let result = {};
    for (const i in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[i] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
        const temp = flattenObj(obj[i]);
        for (const j in temp) {
          result[i + "_" + j] = temp[j];
        }
      } else {
        result[i] = obj[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function getData() {
    try {
      let result = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20");
      let resultData = result.data.results.map((data) => flattenObj(data));
      setUsers(resultData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  const sortByName = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    let sorted = useMemo(() => {
      let clonedUsers = [...users];
      clonedUsers.sort((a, b) => a.name_first.localeCompare(b.name_first));
      return clonedUsers;
    }, [users]);
    return sorted;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="column" onClick={sortByName}>
              Name
            </th>
            <th scope="column">Location Street Number</th>
            <th scope="column">Location City</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {users.map((value, idx) => {
          return (
            <>
              <tbody key={idx}>
                <tr>
                  <td>{value.name_first}</td>
                  <td>{value.location_street_number}</td>
                  <td>{value.location_city}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't have to rerender'? If you want to sort the data, that sounds like you need to rerender it.

Comment: If I directly update the users state then it has to re-render, but if I use useMemo then there is no need to re-render, thus performance optimization.

Comment: But don't you want to see the sorted data visually? That means it needs to rerender.

Answer (score 3):

No *React* hook can be conditionally invoked!

But you can avoid running into this problem by declaring it always. In your case, take your `useMemo` out of the function call and use it as a regular assignment.

```js
function App() {
  ... 

  let sorted = useMemo(() => {
    let clonedUsers = [...users];
    clonedUsers.sort((a, b) => a.name_first.localeCompare(b.name_first));
    return clonedUsers;
  }, [users]);

  ...
  
  return ...
}
```

The above means it's not driven by the click. However after you clicked, you could change other states, ex. `users`, thus making the `useMemo` to calculate the new values. `useMemo` is an advanced assignment statement which only gets kicked in when any dependency changes.

To be honest, you did everything right except the conditional hook part.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this is a good example of premature optimisation, and should be avoided (at first). This answer means that the sort is ran every time the users array changes, even if the column header is never clicked. I would initally just run the sort on click, updating the state. If performance became a problem, then you could cache the sorted result asynchronously on load, or setup some sort of pagination. Either way you should avoid this answer initially.

Comment: That is true @MattWay. I answered this question assuming he's trying to accomplish a classical `useMemo` case. But you are absolutely right, if there's no other states or props inside this component that he want to decouple from the update, then he shouldn't be using `useMemo`.